# Get Primary Key after Saving a ModelForm in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

How do I get the primary key after saving a ModelForm? After the form has been validated and saved, I would like to redirect the user to the contact_details view which requires the primary key of the contact.

```
def contact_create(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ContactForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse(contact_details, args=(form.pk,)))
    else:
        form = ContactForm()
```

Comment: Exactly what I wanted to ask, thanks! +1

Answer (score 68, accepted):

The [ModelForm](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#modelform)'s [save](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#the-save-method) method returns the saved object.

Try this:

```
def contact_create(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ContactForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            new_contact = form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse(contact_details, args=(new_contact.pk,)))
    else:
        form = ContactForm()
```

Comment: No problem, that's easily overlooked and not immediatly intuitive. ;)

Comment: What's with the `reverse` function?

Comment: It's a django url resolver function, https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#reverse-resolution-of-urls

Answer (score 13):

In the case where you have set form.save(commit=False) because you want to modify data and you have a many-to-many relation, then the answer is a little bit different:

```
def contact_create(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ContactForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            new_contact = form.save(commit=False)
            new_contact.data1 = "gets modified"
            new_contact.save()
            form.save_m2m()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse(contact_details, args=(new_contact.pk,)))
    else:
        form = ContactFrom()
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/forms/modelforms/#the-save-method