# django model instance could not get the field after save

Tags: django, model

Here is my code:

**models.py**

```
class TblUser(models.Model):
    uid = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True, db_column='ID') # Field name made lowercase.
    username = models.CharField(max_length=3072, db_column='UserName', blank=True) # Field name made lowercase.
    password = models.CharField(max_length=3072, db_column='PassWord', blank=True) # Field name made lowercase.
    datesstart = models.DateTimeField(null=True, db_column='datesStart', blank=True) # Field name made lowercase.
    datesend = models.DateTimeField(null=True, db_column='datesEnd', blank=True) # Field name made lowercase.
    num = models.IntegerField(null=True, db_column='Num', blank=True) # Field name made lowercase.
    power = models.IntegerField(null=True, db_column='Power', blank=True) # Field name made lowercase.
    email = models.CharField(max_length=12288, blank=True)
    class Meta:
        db_table = u'tbl_user'

    def __unicode__(self):
        return '%d--%s--%d'%(self.uid,self.username,self.power)
```

**views.py**

```
from app.models import TblUser
def appendUser(self,name,pwd):
    #I add a new user,and the primary_key:uid is autoincrement in datebase
    user = TblUser.objects.create(username=name,password=pwd)
    print user.uid#None
```

When I call the **appendUser()**,it will insert a new record into datebase, and the **user**(TblUser's instance) only have two valid fields(**username,password**), the other is empty.

How can I get the `user.uid` because I want handle other things by using it?

Answer (score 2):

You should use an `AutoField` not an `IntegerField` for the pk: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/models/fields/#autofield

Answer (score 0):

You might want to read this post, different approach using ModelForm:

[Get Primary Key after Saving a ModelForm in Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/732952/get-primary-key-after-saving-a-modelform-in-django)