# Django Form Primary Key on save() method - getting NoneType traceback

Tags: django, django-forms

I was using the q&a at 
[Get Primary Key after Saving a ModelForm in Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/732952/get-primary-key-after-saving-a-modelform-in-django#new-answer).

It's exactly on point with what I need to do.

I have the following model:

```
class meetingEvent(models.Model):
    '''
    A meeting event
    '''

    name = models.CharField(max_length=64, help_text="a name for this meeting")
    account_number = models.ForeignKey(account)
    meeting_type = models.ForeignKey(meetingType)
    meeting_group = models.ForeignKey(meetingGroup)
    start_time = models.DateTimeField(help_text="start time for this event")
    end_time = models.DateTimeField(help_text="end time for this event")
    created_time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    listed_products = models.ForeignKey(product)
    additonal_notes = models.TextField(help_text="additional notes for this meeting")

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

I have the following form:

```
class meetingEventForm(forms.ModelForm):
    """
    to create a new meeting event.
    """
    portal_user = forms.CharField(help_text="username to access portal data")
    portal_pass = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput, help_text="password to add access portal data")

    def save(self, commit=True):

        super(meetingEventForm, self).save(commit=commit)

    class Meta:
        model = meetingEvent
```

I have the following view:

```
def meeting_event(request):

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = meetingEventForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            new_agenda=form.save()

            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('agenda_detail', args=(new_agenda.pk,)))

    else:
        form = meetingEventForm()
        return render_to_response('agendas/event.html',{'form':form,}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

I've confirmed that this makes it into the database cleanly.
However, I get the following error:

```
Traceback:
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/Django-1.5.2-py2.6.egg/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  115.                         response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/Django-1.5.2-py2.6.egg/django/contrib/auth/decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  25.                 return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/var/www/html/tamtools/agendas/views.py" in meeting_event
  44.             return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('agenda_detail', args=(new_agenda.pk,)))

Exception Type: AttributeError at /agendas/add/
Exception Value: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'pk'
```

Has something changed in Django 1.5 that I don't know about? new_agenda should be a meetingEventForm type, shouldn't it?

Comment: Is meetingEventForm a Form or a ModelForm?

Comment: @lborgav In case of Form, he would get `save method not exist` type of error.

Comment: Give us the `meetingEventForm` definition.

Comment: class meetingEventForm(forms.ModelForm):
    """
    to create a new meeting event.
    """
    portal_user = forms.CharField(help_text="username to access portal data")
    portal_pass = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput, help_text="password to add access portal data")

    def save(self, commit=True):

        super(meetingEventForm, self).save(commit=commit)

    class Meta:
        model = meetingEvent

Comment: added meetingEventForm definition to initial question. thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You overwrite save methid in modelform, but you forgot to return model.

```
return super( ....
```

Comment: Glad to help, sorry about poor answer explanation, I wrote it through 'smart' phone.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to override the ModeForm save method, since you aren't doing anything special with it.  Your ModelForm should look like:

```
class MeetingEventForm(forms.ModelForm):
    """
    to create a new meeting event.
    """
    class Meta:
        model = meetingEvent
```

*I also changed the class name to conform with the Python [style guide](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/).*

You also have two extra fields in the form that have nothing to do with your model.  There could be two reasons - one, you need to save these fields in another model, or the second option is that you want someone to authorize themselves before they can add a new event.

Since the second one seems more plausible, restrict access to the form from your view:

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.shorcuts import render, redirect

@login_required()
def meeting_event(request):
    form = MeetingEventForm(request.POST or {})
    context = {'form': form}

    if request.method == 'POST':
        if form.is_valid():
            new_agenda = form.save()
            return redirect('agenda_detail', args=(new_agenda.pk,))
        else:
            return render(request, 'agendas/event.html', context)
    else:
        return render(request, 'agendas/event.html', context)
```

---

As this is a common task, and you are using django 1.5, why not use the generic [class based views](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/class-based-views/)?

Your code will be reduced, and you don't have to worry about the mundane details:

First, in your `views.py`, create a class that inherits from the generic `CreateView` which is used to display a model form for a model, let the user fill it in, and save the details:

```
from django.views.generic.edit import CreateView

class CreateMeetingRequest(CreateView):
    template_name = 'agendas/event.html'
    model = meetingRequest
```

Now, to map the view to a url, we add it to `urls.py`.  Since we also want the user to be logged in before they can add a meeting request - the `login_required` decorator takes care of that for us. It will check if the user is logged in - if not, redirect the user to a login form and once they have logged in, redirect them back to the form:

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

from .views import CreateMeetingRequest

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # your other views
    url(r'meeting-request/add/$',
        login_required(CreateMeetingRequest.as_view()), name='add-meeting-req'),
)
```

Finally, we need to tell the view where to go once the form is successful. `CreateView` will check if the model has a `get_absolute_url` method, and call that. So in your `models.py`:

```
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse

class meetingRequest(models.Model):

    # your normal fields

    def get_absolute_url(self):
       return reverse('agenda_detail', args=(self.pk,))
```

Comment: that's all great advice, and I may well take advantage of some of it later on. However, I do need several of the aspects you omitted. I just didn't paste it all in so it wouldn't make things confusing. I somehow forgot to return the saved instance in my super'd save function. bone-had mistake solved! :)

Comment: Yeah but the point is you are writing code that isn't doing anything. The only point of overriding a method is to change its default behavior - which you haven't done. If you had simply removed your custom `save` method, it would have worked.

Comment: I haven't changed the default behavior ... in the example. Thanks again for the help!